# NavigationView and Toolbar be overlaid by content

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, drawerlayout, navigationview

I'm trying to implement material navigation drawer using

- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

The problem is both NavigationView & Toolbar always be overlaid by FrameContent. A FrameContent just a fragment.

***NOTE**: I had tried LinearLayout replace for RelativeLayout as container, but not work.

activity_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></FrameLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

protected Toolbar mToolbar;
protected NavigationView mNavigationView;
protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
protected FrameLayout container;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.material_activity_layout);

    this.mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(this.mToolbar);

    this.mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    this.mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
    this.mNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.drawer);

    this.mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle defaultActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            this.mDrawerLayout,
            this.mToolbar,
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };

    this.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(defaultActionBarDrawerToggle);

    defaultActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    this.mToolbar.setTitle("Test Toolbar");
    this.mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new InFragment(), "fragment").commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

public static class InFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

}

Here the result

[image: result 1]

[image: result 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not override **@android:id/content** because it cause some odd behaviour so just introduce a new id like **@+id/fragmentcontainer** and use it.

When you are adding an fragment with **android.R.id.content** and there is already some content it will be placed above the other content.

Also change the order that **toolbar** is before the rest of the content like the framelayout etc.

Hope it helps

Edit: I did adapt my old answer since it was not 100% correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LinearLayout`  with `android:orientation="vertical"` instead `RelativeLayout`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but why are you creating  another FrameLayoutin in frgment.  Create fresh android:id="@+id/content"` instead  android:id="@android:id/content"